# Is there a way to be notified when Task.Status changes to running?

Tags: c#, events, async-await, inotifypropertychanged

I'm writing a class that runs tasks and notifies based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

One problem I can't think of a solution for is how to notify when Task.Status goes from `TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation` to `TaskStatus.Running`.

Shortened code below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public abstract class ExecutionTracker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected ExecutionTracker(Task task)
    {
        Task = task;
        AwaitTask(task);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Task Task { get; }

    public TaskStatus Status => Task.Status;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private async void AwaitTask(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            // This is where status goes from WaitingForActivation to Running
            // and I want to do OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status)) when it happens.
            // A hack would be setting a flag awaiting = true here and return TaskStatus.Running if the flag is true.
            // ^ feels nasty
            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
            // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause We don't want to propagate errors here. Just make them bindable.
        catch
        {
        }

        // Signal propertychanges depending on result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't (efficiently). And you're probably doing something wrong, and/or making some invalid assumptions if you think you need this.

Many Tasks never transition to the `TaskStatus.Running` state. For example, all tasks created from a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (including those returned by async methods) go straight from `WaitingForActivation` to one of the 3 completed states. And no Task ever exposes to its callers when it transitions to `Running` (if indeed, it does at all).

The only way you could possibly know *roughly* when it happens (besides polling, which would be awful) would be if you ensured that all the tasks were scheduled on your custom `TaskScheduler` and thus knew when you were about to execute them. But as I say, you're really swimming upstream here and should rethink any design that you think depends on this.