# How to track Task's status with extension method?

Tags: c#

I am new to asynchronous programming. Trying to create correct extension method which can print status of task if it has changed. But i dont know how to do it. Thats what i have now:

```
static class MyAsync
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task t = MyAsync.PrintCountPrimesAsync(35);
        t.Tracking();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public static async Task PrintCountPrimesAsync(int n) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"CountOfPrimes = { await CustomMath.GetPrimesCountAsync(100000, 100000)}");


    public static async Task Tracking(this Task task)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TaskStatus current = task.Status;
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (current != task.Status)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
                    current = task.Status;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomMath
{
    public static Task<int> GetPrimesCountAsync(int start, int count)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            ParallelEnumerable.Range(start, count).Count(n =>
                Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i > 0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a hot loop over the task status; that would be *incredibly* expensive - each usage of `Tracking` will max a core until it has completed; in reality, a task only has two interesting statuses: "not done", and "done" (which includes with failure) - why not just log something when it completes, *in the actual method you're running*?

Comment: @Marc Gravell Hello, Marc. Thanks for your answer. Because that my task. I have to create extension method which will be track all statuses of task.

Comment: What is the end goal? I can't imagine the user would care about such things, and task status can be viewed in the debugger if needed for development.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to be notified when Task.Status changes to running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811639/is-there-a-way-to-be-notified-when-task-status-changes-to-running)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn im going to check. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to use a `Progress` object to message the progrss of the task to the caller [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19020.progress-of-a-task-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *ideal* answer to this is "don't", but if you *absolutely must*, `ContinueWith` acts as a callback that might be suitable here:

```cs
public static void Tracking(this Task task)
    => _ = task.ContinueWith(static x => Console.WriteLine(x.Status));
```

This only tracks completion (with or without fault), but: that's pretty much the only interesting and reliable state transition *anyway*.

Comment: Thank you, your answers are very valuable as usual!

Answer (score 1):

I linked the SO post that says it's unpractical to do that.

So, if you really need this, this is something you could use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = GetPrimes();
    while (t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) ;
}
```

But if do it like this specifically, it's going to do the same job as `await` opreator would do, but this blocks the thread.

So basically you would need to have some loop watching over tasks' statuses. You could add some `Task.Delay`s no to block the thread.

But still, I would not recommend going that path.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to tackle this with a callback.

Try this:

```
class CustomMath
{
    public static Task<int> GetPrimesCountAsync(int start, int count, Action<TaskStatus> track)
    {
        Task<int> task = null;
        task = Task.Run(() =>
            ParallelEnumerable.Range(start, count).Count(n =>
            {
                track(task.Status);
                return Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n % i > 0);
            }));
        return task;
    }
}
```

I'm using the `Action<TaskStatus> track` and injecting it in to the calculation. It then allows the calculation to control when to report back the status.

Now you can run this code:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var x = await CustomMath.GetPrimesCountAsync(1, 5, ts => Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
4
```

Comment: Thanks! But i must to do it with extension method, but your solution is really good and better than what i must to do